# Accessing variables from Parent Class

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, parent-child, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UIPageViewController`.

My Class - `ViewController` (which contains all the code and is the data source) runs instances of `PageItemController`.

My UIPageControl (`pControl`) is displayed in a Navigation Bar in `ViewController`.

I would something like the following code:

**PageItemController**

```
override func viewDidAppear(){

    let vController = the parent view controller // ViewController
    vController.pControl.currentPage = itemIndex

}
```

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `parentViewController` property on your view controller:

```
if let parentVC = self.parentViewController as? MyParentViewController {
    itemIndex = parentVC.pControl // set variable here
}
```

Comment: In my case would I say `if let parentVC = self.parentViewController as? ViewController `? And does this work because I created the instance of `PageItemController` inside `ViewController`? .. The above code is returning false for me

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
    // Get the Navigation Controller
    let navControl = self.navigationController

    // Get all the pages in the hierarchy
    let allPages = navControl!.viewControllers

    // Get the current page
    let thisPageViewController = navControl!.visibleViewController

    // Work out which is the current page.
    // I'm sure someone else will have a more elgant way of doing this.
    let arrayOfPages : NSArray = NSArray(array: allPages)
    let thisPageIndex = arrayOfPages.indexOfObject(thisPageViewController)

    // Now get the parent and set a value in it.
    if thisPageIndex > 0 {
        let parentPageIndex = thisPageIndex - 1
        let parentView: AnyObject = arrayOfPages[parentPageIndex]
        parentView.pControl.currentPage = thisPageIndex
    } else {
        println("We are at the top and had to stop.")
    }
```